# Bitnami Drupal with apache + nginx is a mirage?

Tags: apache, nginx, drupal, bitnami

I installed nginx on Debian 10 with Bitnami Drupal 9.0.3, tried to run apache and nginx on different ports (one on 80 and the other on 8080) but not only does it not work, but doesn't even restart bitnami (Failed to start LSB: bitnami init script).
I need both web servers but understand what I did too much (or didn't do and that was needed) and how to have these two with bitnami drupal; it looks like a mirage.

I am not experienced, I followed some guides and some advice close to my case. So I don't know what to report, if you tell me I will report the various requested codes. Meanwhile, I report the apache logs:

```
[Fri Jan 29 15:48:32.228193 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10873:tid 139859847469952] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 29 15:48:32.754162 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 11358:tid 140455115254656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 29 15:48:32.754268 2021] [core:notice] [pid 11358:tid 140455115254656] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf'
[Fri Jan 29 15:48:35.744082 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 11358:tid 140455115254656] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 29 15:48:45.994050 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 11917:tid 140693937834880] AH00489: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 29 15:48:45.994143 2021] [core:notice] [pid 11917:tid 140693937834880] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf'
[Fri Jan 29 16:29:06.856707 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 11917:tid 140693937834880] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Many thanks to all you, guys.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. First of all, let's stop the system's NGINX server and start the Bitnami's Apache `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start`. Are all the services started? `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`

Comment: I want to run nginx (change from apache to on nginx) but, despite having followed the official bitnami guide, something is not right. regarding your questions: the bitnami service starts; while the status is apache not running, mariadb already running, php-fpm already running. Thanks for any support.

Comment: If you want to use NGINX, I suggest you install/deploy the Bitnami NGINX solution and then deploy the Drupal app by following [the Bitnami guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/nginx/administration/create-custom-application-php/)